# What are the keys in redux-persist v5 config's blacklist and whitelist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

i tried to persist my redux store to sessionStorage and i want one reducer not to persist. i tried to add its name in blacklist array but it still persisting the whole store.
Can you guys tell me what are the keys in config.
in docs it showing like this

```
{
 key: string, // the key for the persist
 storage: Object, // the storage adapter, following the AsyncStorage api
 version?: number, // the state version as an integer (defaults to -1)
 blacklist?: Array<string>, // do not persist these keys
 whitelist?: Array<string>, // only persist they keys
 migrate?: (Object, number) => Promise<Object>,
 transforms?: Array<Transform>,
 throttle?: number,
 keyPrefix?: string, // will be prefixed to the storage key
 debug?: boolean, // true -> verbose logs
 stateReconciler?: false | StateReconciler, // false -> do not 
 automatically reconcile state
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It refers to your sub reducer keys, but one level deep (it's maybe your problem).

An exemple

You create your main reducer like this

```
export default combineReducers({
  app,
  auth,
  comments
});
```

If you want to only persist your `comments` reducer, you can use `whitelist: ['comments']` or `blacklist: ['app', 'auth']`.
If you want to blacklist or whitelist something deeper, you should see redux-persist-transform-filter.

Answer (score 0):

your index.js in redux should be like this:

```
import {persistCombineReducers} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage';

// You have to import every reducers and combine them.
import {reducer as UserReducer} from './UserReducer';
import {reducer as CommentReducer} from './CommentReducer';
import {reducer as ProductRedux} from './ProductRedux';

const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  blacklist: [
    'Comment',
    'Product',
  ],
};

export default persistCombineReducers(config, {
  user: UserReducer,
  comment: CommentReducer,
  product: ProductRedux,
});
```

Comment: hi @Kamelj, can you explain what `key: 'root'` means?